# For a stats systems what's better in MySQL: InnoDB, Archive or MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, archive, myisam, statistics

I want **to store all accesses to a webpage** with user-agent, script-execution-time, request-uri, full referer and some more variables.

What I have been doing is use normalized MyISAM tables like:

```
stats
stats_user_agents
stats_referers
stats_requested_uris
```

But in a normal webpage this takes **some SELECT's** and **1 INSERT**.

It's better use ARCHIVE tables?

The stats records will be from 0 to some millions.

Comment: What is your target? query performance (and what kind)? storage?  reliability? easy to maintain?

Comment: @tszming: Performance and storage, I wanna save all data and get it in a stats section of the webpanel.

Comment: I would recommend you also look at those column oriented storege engines for MySQL such as Infobright (http://www.infobright.org/images/com_images/Log_Mgt_Final.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some basic comparisons [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html) between isam, compressed isam, archive and innodb engines.

Short answer is ISAM is fastest for storing, retrieving and slicing the data.

Comment: I think that so, I can use INSERT DELAYED to speed up things and add a cron to compress the table. I will wait for more answers.